# form:select don't save value in the database

Tags: spring, hibernate

In my current spring project, some fields from my entities are mapped in the views by a `select` tag. This tag is implemented through the spring form tag form:select, in one of this two ways:

```
<form:select path="${entry.key}" class="form-control">
    <form:option value="${null}" label="--Selecione"></form:option>
    <form:options items="${values[entry.key]}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="nome" class="form-control">
    </form:options>
</form:select>
```

or

```
<form:select path="${entry.key}.id" class="form-control">
    <form:option value="${null}" label="--Selecione"></form:option>
    <form:options items="${values[entry.key]}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="nome" class="form-control">
    </form:options>
</form:select>
```

renderized for this html code:

```
<select id="pagina" name="pagina" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Selecione</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="1">one</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<select id="pagina" name="pagina.id" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Selecione</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="1">one</option>
</select>
```

the entity class is that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pagina")
public class Pagina {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome", unique=true, nullable=false, length=32)
    @Order(value=1)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "titulo", nullable=false, length=32)
    @Order(value=2)
    private String titulo;

    @Column(name="resumo", length=140)
    @Order(value=3)
    private String resumo;

    @Column(name = "descricao", length=65535)
    @Order(value=4)
    private String descricao;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="pagina")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @Order(value=5)
    private Pagina pagina;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="produto")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @Order(value=6)
    private Produto produto;
}
```

when I use the first option, the data is stored in the database but without the foreign key values, which remain null.

when I use the second option, if I try insert or update a new item in the database, I get an error:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.spring.loja.model.pagina.persistence.model.Pagina.nome
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.persistence.Dao.persist(Dao.java:33)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.persistence.Dao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ddbbe880.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.spring.loja.model.pagina.persistence.PaginaHome$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6470cd.persist(<generated>)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.service.service.cadastra(service.java:39)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.service.service$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c92a3159.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.spring.loja.model.pagina.service.PaginaService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8aedfbd5.cadastra(<generated>)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.controller.controller.cadastra(controller.java:88)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.controller.controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c8cc444b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640)
    at com.spring.loja.model.pagina.controller.PaginaController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cc3f49f7_2.cadastra(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
public ModelAndView cadastra() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    mav.setViewName("private/cadastrar");
    mav.addObject("command", this.entityClass.newInstance());
    mav.addObject("entity", this.getName());
    mav.addObject("map", serv.getListaAtributos());
    mav.addObject("values", serv.getListaValores());

    return mav;
}
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    if(serv.cadastra(object)) {
        return "yes";
    }
    else {
        return "not";
    }
}
```

service class:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
@Transactional
public boolean cadastra(E e) {
    return dao.persist(e);
}
```

dao class:

```
@Transactional
public boolean persist(E transientInstance) {
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
        return true;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't figure out why the above don't work, but I find a solution which works, and in my case it was more fit to the requisites of my application.

the solution I found was this:

**jsp code**

```
        <c:url value="/Categoria/listagem2.json" var="url"/>
        <form:label path="${entry}.id" class="label label-default">${entry}</form:label>
        <form:select path="${entry}.id" class="form-control select" data-lista="${url}">
        </form:select>
```

**jquery code**

```
$("select.select").each(function(){
    var target = $(this);
    var lista = $(this).data('lista');
    load_options(target, lista);
});

function load_options(target, lista) {
    target.empty();
    target.append("<option class=\"form-control\" value=\"\"></option>");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: lista
    }).done(function(data){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(json.item, function(index, item) {
            target.append('<option class="form-control" value="'+item.id+'">'+item.nome+'</option>');
        });
    });
}
```

I still need correct the line `target.append("<option class=\"form-control\" value=\"\"></option>");`, but I am sure this works after test with a hardcoded example.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you use Map object in your controller get method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/paginapage.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String goTopage(Map myMap){

myMap.put("pagina",new Pagina());

return "jsppage";

}
```

and on your jsp page

```
<form:form method="post" action="paginacontroller.html" commandName="pagina">

    <form:select path="nome" class="form-control">

    </form:select>

</form:form>
```

you are getting the error because in your annotation you indicate that it should not be null but you retrieved a null value.

first if you put a Pagina() object in your map and you can use it to your form spring like the example above. the `commandName="pagina"` refers to Pagina() object and the `path` in select element refers that it is the nome field in Pagina() object.

in your controller you could have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/paginacontroller.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(Pagina paginaForm,HttpServletRequest request){

//call your service layer here to process the form.
//the Pagina() object here came from the form using the path, the value of the elements are stored in the fields. the path should be equal to the variable name (ex. path="nome" pagina.nome variable)
return "jsppage";
}
```

Comment: Ok, my controller methods are a bit different of what you suggest. I add them to my question. Can you see what's wrong with them?

Comment: the problem is that you are getting null value in you nome field which you indicate that it should not be null with `nullable=false`, so you are getting the problem in your form spring maybe the nome field is not directed to your entity class

Comment: But the field really can't be null. When I inform a null value for the foreign key, I want store in the database a blank value for it, and not try persist a empty entity (it's what the application is trying to do).

Comment: if you want to insert nome to the database as blank then check if it is null. if it is null setNome("");